# Scheduling script on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I know we can schedule script run in gitlab(I've not done it yet: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html)

Before starting this all I had doubt, suppose I want to run python script which uses pandas library then how script can run because gitlab doesn't have env which has pandas installed in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can include installing `panda` in a job’s script. The Gitlab runner with install panda and then carry out your other jobs defined in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` (including your script).

```yaml
---
  run script:
    script:
      - pip install panda
      - python script.py
```